# Access denied for user '...'@'%' (using password: YES)

Tags: heroku, cleardb

I am using ClearDB in Heroku accessing via Mysql workbench and whatever I do, it just gives me privilege error. Even though, I have all the privileges already

I did:
`SHOW GRANTS;`

and it says I have all the grants

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Did not work

Comment: Well, something is not right with the username and/or password or access to the requested resource there.